# PHP Simple Post - Post Parameters empty

Tags: php, post, http-post, postman

I am making a simple review application.  The below image is my DB schema:

[image]

Here is the PHP I am using to accept the post request:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = ($_POST["name"]);
    $title1 = ($_POST["phone"]);
    $title2 = ($_POST["myphone"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    $image = ($_POST["stars"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

    mysql_query("insert into `PeerReview` 
                        ( `ReviewerPhoneNumber`, `RevieweePhoneNumber`, 
                          `RevieweeName`, `Comments`, `Stars` ) 
                values ( '".$title2."', '".$title1."', '".$name."', '".$image."', '".$image."')");
    if (mysql_error()) {
        die(mysql_error());

        echo '
             <div class="post" style="border-bottom:1px black solid;">
              <h3>Thank You!</h3>
              </div>
              </body>
              </html>';
        die();
    }
}
```

I am using Postman to send the post request:

[image]

The result is a new row being added to my DB with an Auto-incremented ID, but blank values for every other column.  This is incorrect because as you can see in Postman I am accurately adding the parameters.  I have made many PHP applications before using this same technology stack.  I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Please port all code as text and not as pictures

Comment: any error? Also if you paste the code instead on screen shot, it will be great

Comment: Simply a missing `"` in the `mysql_query()` line

Comment: @RiggsFolly Reposted code as text

Comment: @FullSTack01 reposted code as text

Comment: @RiggsFolly Where is the missing "?  I have validated that the PHP is correct.  The last input parameter is an integer.  Can you please explain how this is duplicate? neither of your suggestions offer an answer mysql is working throughout my website.

Comment: Now the code is sensibly formatted do you see one obvious error?

Comment: And it might be useful to know what the function `test_input()` does

Comment: And for some reason you are adding `$image` to 2 columns. Do the datatypes of those 2 columns match what you are passing?

Comment: @RiggsFolly $image is added correctly to 2 columns.  One is contained in quotes for a varchar, the other is without for an INT.  There is NO PHP error either, therefore I do not see how this can be a duplicate.

Comment: @RiggsFolly please explain how this is duplicate.  I am successfully using mysql elsewhere and there is no PHP error because a row is added into the DB which would not happen with an error.  You have closed my question without reason, please reopen.

Comment: Did you notice yet that you only output anything if you  get a `mysql_error()`